# POST from Angular to Laravel not working

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, rest, laravel

I have been working on a REST API that is working correctly.  Through a client like Postman, I can test and see my changes, deletions, additions, etc. working as long as I encode the data with `x-www-form-urlencoded`

However now I'm trying to hook it up with Angular.  I can make a GET request just fine, the POST is what's hanging me up.

Here's my scratch directive doing the dirty work in Angular .js (I know I need to create a service for this):

```
app.directive('addGoal', function($http) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'js/templates/add-goal.html',
        link: function(scope) {
            scope.submit = function(data) {
                data = {
                    goal: {
                        summary: "asdf",
                        details: "asdf",
                        start_date: "2014-01-01",
                        end_date: "2014-01-02"
                    }
                };
                console.log(data);
                $http({
                    url: 'http://localhost:8000/v1/goal/',
                    method: 'POST',
                    data: data,
                    headers: {'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'}
                }).
                success(function() {
                    console.log(data);
                }).
                error(function() {
                    console.log('error');
                });
            };
        }
    };
});
```

The call is fired and the `.success() function` operates normally, however the data isn't POSTed in my API and therefore not saved to the database.

When I get a response back, it acts like the formatting isn't right, as it errors out on validation:

```
{"error":true,"message":{"summary":["The summary field is required."],"details":["The details field is required."],"start_date":["The start date field is required."],"end_date":["The end date field is required."]}}
```

Just for reference, here is the store() function of my Controller in Laravel doing the API work:

```
public function store()
{
    $goal = new Goal;
    $goal->summary = Request::get('summary');
    $goal->details = Request::get('details');
    $goal->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
    $start_date_entered = Request::get('start_date');
    $end_date_entered = Request::get('end_date');
    $goal->start_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($start_date_entered));
    $goal->end_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($end_date_entered));

    $validation = Validator::make(Request::all(), [
        'summary' => 'required|max:255',
        'details' => 'required|max:255',
        'start_date' => 'required|date',
        'end_date' => 'required|date'
    ]);

    if ($validation->fails())
    {
        $messages = $validation->messages();
        return Response::json(array(
            'error' => true,
            'message' => $messages),
            200
        );
    }
    else
    {
        $goal->save();

        return Response::json(array(
            'error' => false,
            'goal' => $goal->toArray()),
            200
        );
    }
}
```

I created a test route like this:

```
Route::post('/test', function()
{
    // First we fetch the Request instance
    $request = Request::instance();

    // Now we can get the content from it
    $content = $request->getContent();

    var_dump($content);
});
```

And surprisingly my response back looked like this:

```
string(94) "{"goal":{"summary":"asdf","details":"asdf","start_date":"2014-01-01","end_date":"2014-01-02"}}"
```

If the success function is firing, it's hitting the API, right?  How can I troubleshoot this more to find out the real problem?  I'm stuck on where I should go next to get this data into the API so it can store it properly, as it's doing in the REST client.

**EDIT**

After review, the actual problem involved the way I set up Laravel and it's inability to understand that JSON was being passed in.  A simple fix involved changing the `Request::get` to `Input::json()->get()`:

```
$goal->summary = Input::json()->get('summary');
```

Comment: angular will send data as `application/json` in request body which is exactly what you see in the var_dump. json_decode it instead of using post methods

Comment: Turns out, in a way your comment is the answer.  The JSON isn't expected on the API, which I totally was unaware of.  So, as soon as I submitted it in a URL string like `summary=asdf&details=asdf&start_date=Jan+1+2014&end_date=Jan+2+2014` it worked like a charm.

Comment: but you are limted to query string length, much simpler to json_decode the request body

Comment: It looks like I'll just need to re-write my larval Controllers to take the JSON and decode from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use Telerik fiddler : http://www.telerik.com/fiddler for such purpose. It gives following information.

1. Request details, like data, method, request headers, Auth headers, cookies etc.
2. Response details, data, headers

It also allows us to replay the given request by modifying the method and data to check how service behaves with different inputs.

Hope it helps.

Moreover,
I think even if you change the data format like follows, it should work.

```
               data = {
                        summary: "asdf",
                        details: "asdf",
                        start_date: "2014-01-01",
                        end_date: "2014-01-02"  
                };
```

Comment: That doesn't want to work for me, although I can see where you were going with that.  I did just confirm however that sending a url-like string like: `summary=asdf&details=asdf&start_date=Jan+1+2014&end_date=Jan+2+2014` worked like a charm.

Comment: I am not sure but Can you please try once, Input::post('summary') // for $_POST instead of Request::get('summary')

Comment: Input::post('summary') complains, here's the response back from Laravel:
`{"error":{"type":"Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalErrorException","message":"Call to undefined method Illuminate\\Http\\Request::post()","file":"\/vagrant\/laravel\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Support\/Facades\/Facade.php","line":208}}`

Comment: I just tried this in my post store() method in Laravel and it returned back successfully:
    `$goal = new Goal;
    $goal->summary = Input::json()->get('summary');
    return $goal;`

I can probably take it from there and get what I need.

Comment: Ok great it worked.:)   I had strong feel that retrieving from $_POST is messing something.

Comment: What do you mean by "retrieving from $_POST" the big problem is probably me not understanding what that means, how it relates from the API I've got with Laravel.

Comment: Ah! I just meant the posted values to API.